# AWS Glue Job PySpark : Bookmark enable but not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I run pyspark job that takes JSON data from source S3, makes little transforms and stored it in target S3 as parquet :

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext, DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, dayofmonth, hour

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Load data from S3 using Glue context
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "vp-kfh-data-database", table_name = "vp_kfh_data")

# Apply transformations
datasource0 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [
    ("created_at", "string", "created_at", "string"),
    ("updated_at", "string", "updated_at", "string"),
    ("retailer_profile_id", "int", "retailer_profile_id", "int"),
    ("region", "string", "country", "string"),
    ("distinct_id", "string", "distinct_id", "string"),
    ("user_gender", "string", "user_gender", "string"),
    ("order_id", "string", "order_id", "string"),
    ("product_title", "string", "product_title", "string"),
    ("product_category", "string", "product_category", "string"),
    ("product_id", "string", "product_id", "string"),
    ("product_url", "string", "product_url", "string"),
    ("quantity", "long", "quantity", "long"),
    ("currency", "string", "currency", "string"),
    ("current_total_price", "double", "current_total_price", "double"),
], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

# Resolve choice type conflicts
datasource0 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasource0, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice1")

# Drop null fields
datasource0 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = datasource0, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields1")

# Extract partition columns
datasource0 = datasource0.resolveChoice(specs = [('created_at','cast:timestamp')])
datasource0 = datasource0.apply_mapping([
    ("retailer_profile_id", "int", "retailer_profile_id", "int"),
    ('created_at', 'timestamp', 'created_at', 'timestamp'),
    ('created_at', 'timestamp', 'year', 'int'),
    ('created_at', 'timestamp', 'month', 'int'),
    ('created_at', 'timestamp', 'day', 'int'),
    ('created_at', 'timestamp', 'hour', 'int')
])

# Convert back to DynamicFrame for writing as Parquet format with bookmarking
datasource0 = datasource0.toDF()
datasource0 = datasource0.withColumn('year', year(datasource0['created_at']))
datasource0 = datasource0.withColumn('month', month(datasource0['created_at']))
datasource0 = datasource0.withColumn('day', dayofmonth(datasource0['created_at']))
datasource0 = datasource0.withColumn('hour', hour(datasource0['created_at']))
datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource0, glueContext, "final")

# Write the cleaned data back to S3 in Parquet format with bookmarking enabled
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource0,
                                            connection_type = "s3",
                                            connection_options = {"path": "s3://vp-clean-data/data/clean-parquet/",
                                                                  "partitionKeys": ["retailer_profile_id", "year", "month", "day", "hour"]},
                                            format = "parquet",
                                            transformation_ctx = "datasink")

job.commit()
```

The Job bookmark option is enabled, so the job each run needs to take only new records from source S3...
But the job takes each run of all data from source S3 and writes duplicates in target S3.
So how possible to fix it?